# Find all references does not work in Visual Studio 2015 for an ASP.NET web site

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am working with Visual Studio 2015, target framework 4.5.

Find All References(<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>) works perfectly on desktop and ASP.NET web application, but does not work with ASP.NET web site.

I created the web site as follows:

1. File -> New -> Web Site -> Visual C# -> ASP.NET Empty Web Site -> Create As-> NewWebSite
2. Right click on Solution -> Add -> New Project -> Class Library -> ClassLibrary1.cs
3. NewWebSite -> Right Click -> Add -> Add New Item -> Web Form -> Default.aspx
4. NewWebSite (Right Click) -> Add -> Reference -> Solution -> ClassLibrary1 -> Ok

`ClassLibrary1.cs` and `Default.aspx` files code is this:

ClassLibrary1 -> Class1 Code

```
using System;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static string demo = "demo";
    }
}
```

Default.aspx.cs Code

```
using System;
using ClassLibrary1;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = Class1.demo;
    }
}
```

Please close `Default.aspx.cs` file. And <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> on ClassLibrary1 -> Class1 -> Demo

I can't get reference of Demo which does exist in Default.aspx.cs file

Comment: Do you get any errors from debugger?

Comment: No, I didn't get any Error. Did you create project as above?

Comment: If you create project as above you can get what is exact problem is.

Comment: I'm using an older version (2008) of visual studio, but it all seems to work fine for me. Both in website as you described and as an identical console application (instead of website).

Comment: Also, I was worked on Visual Studio 2008 it's work fine. But it's not work in Visual Studio 2015.